# Writing .x files

Tags: c#, geometry, xna, .x

I have a bunch of polygons that are generated by my program (i.e. I manually calculate the position vectors for the vertices). I want to dump these to a .x file (or .fbx or any format I could reload later with XNA). Is there any C# or XNA API for doing this?

10x!

Yoyo

Answer (score 1):

You could try [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924(XNAGameStudio.10).aspx)'s `Serialize()` and `Deserialize()` methods to save and recall your polygons, as well as anything else in your program.